# React-Native Firebase: How to show ALWAYS the notification banner?

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm setting up notifications for a react-native app by using react-native-firebase. iOS works, in Android I have strange behaviour, that the notification banner only shows if there is already another notification sitting in the bar.

Problem Demonstration:
send the same message twice, the first message is only displayed in the upper bar, the second message is shown with a banner.

Goal:
I want the notifications to be always shown with a banner.

[image: problem demonstration]

I listen for messages on android and generate local notifications. I was hoping to have the notification always showing by setting show_in_foreground: true. But that is only partially the case. The behavior in the gif above is the same for the app being in the foreground or background.

```
this.messagingListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {

        const { data} = message;
        const localNotification = new  firebase.notifications.Notification({
          show_in_foreground: true,
          sound: 'default'
        })
        .android.setChannelId('fcm_default_channel')
        .setTitle(data.title)
        .setBody(data.body)
        .android.setColor('#222222') // you can set a color here
        .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High);
        firebase.notifications()
          .displayNotification(localNotification)
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be a Android 10 problem. The notification works fine on Android 9.0. I will update this answer as soon as i know more about a fix for Android 10.